# Curvature of set of points

Tags: python, curve

[data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiuikxlosf6jqi3/profile_nonoisebigd02.txt?dl=0)

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

#initial data
data=np.loadtxt('profile_nonoisebigd02.txt')
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
```

[image: initial profile]

```
#first derivatives 
dx= np.gradient(data[:,0])
dy = np.gradient(data[:,1])

#second derivatives 
d2x = np.gradient(dx)
d2y = np.gradient(dy)

#calculation of curvature from the typical formula
curvature = np.abs(dx * d2y - d2x * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy)**1.5
```

[image: curvature]

Can anyone help me out as to where am I going wrong with the curvature ? 
The set of points give me a parabola, but curvature is not what I expect.

Comment: Seems that both pictures are the same.

Comment: I get expected results with your code. Can you post the snippet you've used to create the two plots?

Comment: plt.scatter(x,y) for the initial plot, and plt.scatter(x,curvature) for the curvature plot.

Comment: Still can't reproduce your issue. Consider posting a subset of `data`, maybe something like `data[::data.shape[0]//25]`.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I have added the whole data file. Btw is d2x, d2y calculated the right way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your data just isn't smooth enough; I used pandas to replace x, y, dx, dy, d2x, d2y and curvature by rolling means for different values window sizes. As the window size increases, the curvature starts to look more and more like what you'd expect to see for a smooth parabola (legend gives window size):

[image]

For the reference, here is the plot of your original data:

[image]

The code used to create the smoothed frames:

```
def get_smooth(smoothing=10, return_df=False):
    data=np.loadtxt('profile_nonoisebigd02.txt')

    if return_df:
        return pd.DataFrame(data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by=0).reset_index(drop=True).rolling(smoothing).mean().dropna()

    # first derivatives
    df['dx'] = np.gradient(df[0])
    df['dy'] = np.gradient(df[1])

    df['dx'] = df.dx.rolling(smoothing, center=True).mean()
    df['dy'] = df.dy.rolling(smoothing, center=True).mean()

    # second derivatives
    df['d2x'] = np.gradient(df.dx)
    df['d2y'] = np.gradient(df.dy)

    df['d2x'] = df.d2x.rolling(smoothing, center=True).mean()
    df['d2y'] = df.d2y.rolling(smoothing, center=True).mean()


    # calculation of curvature from the typical formula
    df['curvature'] = df.eval('abs(dx * d2y - d2x * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 1.5')
    # mask = curvature < 100

    df['curvature'] = df.curvature.rolling(smoothing, center=True).mean()

    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    return df[0], df.curvature
```